# How to get official site for a keyword in search engine

Tags: search-engine

How can we get official site for a keyword in search results?.

For example:
Bing(USA) gives best result at top of search and sayas it as official site, like searching for dell we get dell.com as official site.
Same is true for duckduckgo.com. They show text beside site telling its official site, like if i search for Paris Hilton in DDG , i get parishilton.com as official site.

What are the approaches while determining if a site is official for a keyword?. Do they have repository for all this and manually updates?

How can we proceed for having official site repository mapping a keyword?

Comment: Usually official sites are the top most insearch results, but search engines dont know which is the official site.  Instead they use statistical data based on which site involving the keyword is clicked most.

Comment: But won't that be misleading sort of, a most clicked link might mot be official site. just for an example: people might be searching for Tom Cruise and going to Wikipedia as it has all info, so we will be saying Wikipedia as official one rather than tomcruise.com.

Comment: What @cprogcr said seems right. Instead of using the words "Official site", you can also go for other things, like Google's "I'm feeling lucky"

Comment: But Bing and DDG are going good in giving Official site. Though in DDG, its very limited only for some keywords. So i am thinking they might be maintaining a repository kindof, but from where ? :). Getting information from wikipedia.. just a thought

Comment: Well, when you search "Tom Cruise" for example, google gives you the wikipedia page, and that's because tom cruise's wikipedia article, is the most clicked site involving the keywords tom+cruise. So they only track the clicks based on keywords. If you want to be convinced, look at the JSON search results, and check if there is any entry involving some parameter like: official: "true"

Comment: i think you didn't got my point, it's true Wikipedia is most clicked but that not official tom cruise site, what i mean to say is that tom cruise has its own website and i need to tell user that's the official one, not on how many user are clicking it.

Comment: I was explaining why the wikipedia article shows first and not Tom Cruise's website. There's no repository about official sites. Perhaps [Google Keyword Tool](https://adwords.google.com/o/KeywordTool) could help you understand the thing better.

Comment: I get it what you said. Thanks for your replies and explanation :). But bing and DDG are doing it, so might be they have some kinda repository :P. I still need to dig in how i can too have it :)

Comment: Every site has it's own "repository". So if you want one, I guess you should build one yourself, which of course is kinda impossible. The only way is to filter the results, analyzing them and determine which could be the official site. It's not an easy process. Better move it to chat, it's not good to overload the question with comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16872/discussion-between-cprogcr-and-kailash19)

Answer (score 1):

Use `related` operator with appropriate url in google as follows:

[related:dell.com](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=related%3adell.com&gbv=2&oq=related%3adell.com&gs_l=heirloom-hp.3...831.831.0.1469.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1ac.1.OWBNCX62WoY)

It gives you the official sites of related companies to Dell. Although for most of them it is not explicitly mentioned.
Not sure what you are exactly looking for, but with this method and using a fetcher you can build your own repository.
To having a fun test it with the url of your university's website.

Comment: This service is discontinued.
From Google: `Google Related is an experimental browsing assistant launched to help people find interesting and useful information while they browse the web. The product isn’t experiencing the kind of adoption we’d like, and while we still believe in the value provided to our users, we’ll be retiring the existing product over the next few weeks, so the Related team can focus on creating more magic moments across other Google products.`